# Ordering a list by most occurrences of lowest number

Tags: c#, sorting

I've been playing with this for quite some time now but couldn't figure it out or find an existing question about it. I'm writing a C# tool for race scoring where I need to make an overall result. For this result some special rules apply which I can't figure out the best way to do it:

I've got a list with race results (Winner gets 0 points, 2nd gets 2, 3rd gets 3 etc..). In order to make the results work we first order by a sum of all the points. When that's done there is still a possibility drivers share the same amount of points. In that case we have to look at their best results, for example:

driver 1 has scored: 0 + 0 + 4 = 4
driver 2 has scored: 2 + 2 + 0 = 4

In this case driver 1 would be first because he has the most wins, driver 2 will follow because he has only one win. This should apply for all the participants.

**Update:**
The data model I have looks as following:

```
    public class SerieResultForPilot {
            public long Position { get; set; }
            public Pilot Pilot { get; set; }
            public List<SerieResultEntry> SerieResultEntries { get; set; }
            public long Total { get; set; }
        }

        public class SerieResultEntry {
            public long Points { get; set; }
            public long Penalties { get; set; }
        }
```

The ordering I currently have but doesn't work the right way:

```
       var orderedList = serieResultList.OrderBy(rfp => rfp.Total);
            for (int i = 0; i < pilots.Count; i++) {
                orderedList = orderedList.ThenBy(c => c.SerieResultEntries.Count(sre => sre.Points == i));
            }
```

I hope anyone can help me with a solution for this issue since I couldn't find an issue like this on here yet.

Thanks in advance,
Mark

**Solution**
Compare function

```
    public class SerieResultForPilot {
            public long Position { get; set; }
            public Pilot Pilot { get; set; }
            public List<SerieResultEntry> SerieResultEntries { get; set; }
            public long Total { get; set; }

            public long CompareTo(SerieResultForPilot other) {
                var result = this.Total - other.Total;
                if (result != 0) {
                    return result;
                }
                var thisResults = this.SerieResultEntries.OrderBy(x => x.Points).Select(x => x.Points).ToArray();
                var otherResults = other.SerieResultEntries.OrderBy(x => x.Points).Select(x => x.Points).ToArray();
                for (var i = 0; i < thisResults.Length; i++) {
                    if (thisResults[i] != otherResults[i]) {
                        return thisResults[i] - otherResults[i];
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public class SerieResultEntry {
            public long Points { get; set; }
            public long Penalties { get; set; }
        }
```

Ordering

```
    var orderedList = serieResultList.OrderBy(rfp => rfp.Total);
    foreach (var result in serieResultList) {
          orderedList = orderedList.ThenBy(c => c.CompareTo(result));
    }
```

Comment: Please do not let us assume and post some of your code and examples here

Comment: This seems to be like providing solution than programming issue. Please post your code

Comment: Could you also please provide us with more information on your data model.

Comment: How do you make a difference between 5 time winner and 5time on 4th place ?

Comment: I've updated my question with the data model used.
@mybirthname In that case I suppose they won't have the same points for the overal scoring so the 5 time winner will be above the 5 time 4th at the first ordering by total points

Comment: the easiest (and also flexible way) would be to implement IComparable interface in your SerieResultForPilot class. then just sort (by linq) list of all results. if there will be any change in way you count points (in sailing for example after 5 raced you delete the worst result, and after 9 races you delete 2 of the worse results) you just need to change comparation method, not whole application. take a look to my answer below.

Comment: i've edited your solution to make full usage of interface inheritance and made your comparation method simplier (to strict linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may implement `IComparable` interface in class build around result.

according to your data model compairing method may look something like that

```
public int CompareTo(SerieResultForPilot other){
    var result this.Total - other.Total;
    if (result != 0){
        return result;
    }else{
        var thisResults = this.SerieResultEntries.OrderBy(x => x.SerieResultEntries.Points).toArray();
        var otherResults = his.SerieResultEntries.OrderBy(x => x.SerieResultEntries.Points).toArray();
        for (var i=0; i< thisResults.Count; i++){
            if (thisResults[i] != otherResults[i]){
                return thisResults[i] - otherResults[i];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

documentation of `IComparable` interface is available here https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed! As you said in your other reply it's indeed for landsailing, we have a discard every 4 races but the results are flagged as a discard already so it should be quite easy to implement this. I will update my post with the working version.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most efficient, but I think this would do it:

```
drivers.OrderBy(x => new { x.Sum(y => y.Points), 
    x.Sum(y => y.Points.Where(t => t.Points = 4)), x.Sum(y => y.Points.Where(t => t.Points = 3)) });
```

Assuming points is an Enumerable stored for each driver.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I think all you need to do is replace `ThenBy` with `ThenByDescending`. (You want drivers with *most* low scores at the top of the list.) It also relies on the maximum race score being less than the number of drivers - maybe you need a `<=` rather than `<` in your `for` loop?

It's not the *most* efficient way of doing it, but it's pretty clever - I'd struggle to come up with something that used fewer lines of code.

Comment: That's what I've been playing with but doesn't give the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first find no. of wins and sum of score of each drivers and then sort records based on their score and win as show in below example:

```
public class LinqUtil<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public static void MyScore()
    {
        List<DriverScore> scores = new List<DriverScore>
        {
            new DriverScore {driverId="driver2",score=2 },
            new DriverScore {driverId="driver2",score=2 },
            new DriverScore {driverId="driver2",score=0 },
            new DriverScore {driverId="driver1",score=0 },
            new DriverScore {driverId="driver1",score=0 },
            new DriverScore {driverId="driver1",score=4 },
        };

        var _score = (from s in scores
                    group s by s.driverId into g
                    select new
                    {
                        driverId = g.Key,
                        Win = g.Count(x => x.score == 0),
                        Score = g.Sum(x => x.score)
                    }).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Score).ThenByDescending(x=>x.Win);
        foreach(var _s in _score)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_s.driverId + " " + _s.Win + " " + _s.Score);
        }


    }
}
```